# TreeSet won't sort itself after changing value in JTable

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, treeset

I have a class `Driver`:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Driver implements Comparable<Driver>{

    private static int nextId=0;
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private LocalDate birth;
    private LocalDate hireBegin;
    private LocalDate hireEnd;

    public Driver(){
        super();
    }
    public Driver(String name, LocalDate birth, LocalDate hireBegin, LocalDate hireEnd) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birth = birth;
        this.hireBegin = hireBegin;
        this.hireEnd = hireEnd;
        this.id = nextId;
        nextId++;
    }

     public Driver(String name, String birth,String hireBegin, String hireEnd) {
        this.name = name; 
        DateTimeFormatter formatter =DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
        this.birth = LocalDate.parse(birth,formatter);
        this.hireBegin = LocalDate.parse(hireBegin,formatter);
        this.hireEnd = LocalDate.parse(hireEnd,formatter);
        this.id = nextId;
        nextId++;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getBirth() {
        return birth.toString();
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setBirth(LocalDate birth) {
        this.birth = birth;
    }

     public void setBirth(String birth) {
        this.birth = LocalDate.parse(birth, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    }

    public void setHireBegin(LocalDate hireBegin) {
        this.hireBegin = hireBegin;
    }

    public void setHireBegin(String hireBegin) {
        this.hireBegin = LocalDate.parse(hireBegin, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    }

    public void setHireEnd(LocalDate hireEnd) {
        this.hireEnd = hireEnd;
    }

    public void setHireEnd(String hireEnd) {
        this.hireEnd = LocalDate.parse(hireEnd, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));;
    }

    public String getHireBegin() {
        return hireBegin.toString();
    }

    public String getHireEnd() {
        return hireEnd.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Driver{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", birth=" + birth + ", hireBegin=" + hireBegin + ", hireEnd=" + hireEnd + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Driver o) {
        int result=0;
        result=this.name.compareTo(o.getName());
        if(result==0)
            result = this.id-o.getId();

        return result;
    }

}
```

And I have a `TreeSet` of drivers:

```
private TreeSet<Driver> collDriver = new TreeSet<>();
```

The problem is when I try to change a value of a element in my `JTable`:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col){
try{
        Driver d = getDriverAtRow(row);
        switch(col){
            case 1: 
                d.setName(value.toString());
                break;
            case 2: 
                d.setBirth(value.toString());
                break;  
            case 3: 
                d.setHireBegin(value.toString());
                break;
            case 4: 
                d.setHireEnd(value.toString());
                break;  
            }       


        db.notifyObservers("change in jtable happened");
}
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
        //if(listener !=null){
            //listener.handleTableModelException(new EventCellException(this,"update of cell is doc"));
        //}
    }
```

The `TreeSet` will change the value of the element, but it won't sort the table itself. For example, I printed here the two times the `TreeSet`, one time before I change the value and once after I change it:

```
@Override
public void notifyObservers(Object msg){
    setChanged();
    super.notifyObservers(msg.toString());
    System.out.println(collDriver);
}
```

Output:

```
[Driver{id=1, name=aaa, birth=1111-11-11, hireBegin=1111-11-11, hireEnd=3333-11-14}, Driver{id=0, name=drivername, birth=1111-11-11, hireBegin=1111-11-11, hireEnd=3333-11-14}, Driver{id=2, name=ssss, birth=1111-11-11, hireBegin=1111-11-11, hireEnd=3333-11-14}, Driver{id=3, name=zzz, birth=1111-11-11, hireBegin=1111-11-11, hireEnd=3333-11-14}]
[Driver{id=1, name=aaa, birth=1111-11-11, hireBegin=1111-11-11, hireEnd=3333-11-14}, Driver{id=0, name=drivername, birth=1111-11-11, hireBegin=1111-11-11, hireEnd=3333-11-14}, Driver{id=2, name=ssss, birth=1111-11-11, hireBegin=1111-11-11, hireEnd=3333-11-14}, Driver{id=3, name=qqq, birth=1111-11-11, hireBegin=1111-11-11, hireEnd=3333-11-14}]
```

As you can see the `TreeSet` is no longer sorted, but the value was changed. What could the cause be?

Comment: The reason is that the elements are stored inside the TreeSet by comparing them to other values at the time of their insertion. The TreeSet doesn't re-sort itself when the elements change. And it's a bug, leading to unspecified bahavior, to mutate the elements and thus change their ordering after they've been stored in the set.

Comment: So what would be the best solution be? Delete the driver and insert him again?

Comment: Don't store them in a TreeSet. Store them in a List.

Comment: @JBNizet my task is to do it with a treeset

Comment: That's not a valid, technical, rational argument. What is the TreeSet for? Why do you even need this TreeSet since the drivers are stored in your table model somehow?

Comment: the values from the table model come from the treeset. So whenever I add a new element I add it in my treeset and the table is automatically sorted

Comment: If you must store objects in a `TreeSet`, and any value used in the `compareTo()` method changes, then you *must* remove object from `TreeSet` *before* changing the value, and re-add it *after* changing the value.

Comment: Since `JTable` supports sorting on it's own, I'd consider maintaining the internal structure of the `TableModel` in a `List` of some kind and providing a "export" option which would then generate a new instance of a `TreeSet` based on the current set of values in the `TableModel` - as an idea. Why? Because it's dangerous for the `TableModel` to reliant on a data structure which could be changed outside of it's control